# When specifying VkPipelineStageFlag does it mean start of the stage or end of the stage?

Tags: vulkan

I want to implement some sort of critical section with events - I need to know when I'm able to host-update a vertex buffer. For this, I set an event on the host (`vkSetEvent()`) before recording a command buffer and then record a command to reset the event (`vkCmdResetEvent`). `vkCmdResetEvent` requires to specify the source stage mask to determine when the event is signaled. And here I'm not sure about the stage and couldn't find the needed wording in the specification. If I use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT` do I have a guarantee that the event will be reset at the end of the stage? Or the beginning of the stage?

Comment: It's not clear if your question is about your specific use case (`vkSetEvent` that gets reset with `vkCmdResetEvent`) or something more general (the behavior of pipeline flags).

Comment: The question is about the specific use case. But I thought it can help me to understand the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source stage mask specifies the source of the operations you're synchronizing with. If you specify the source as the vertex shader stage, then you're saying that the operation that you're trying to synchronize with happened either in the VS or before it.

In the case of `vkCmdResetEvent`, there is a need for synchronization so that the reset command doesn't get executed before the command that tests the event happens. So the host sets the event, some later command tests it (perhaps with `vkCmdWaitEvents`, using `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` as its source), and `vkCmdResetEvent` needs to reset it. Well, the latter command needs to use as its source(s) the stage(s) that `vkCmdWaitEvents` set as its *destination*. This ensures that the reset command doesn't get executed before the waits are done.

Answer (score 2):

The stageFlags are to specify in which pipelines the sync operation is to be inserted.

This means that for *source* stages it is after the previous commands complete the stages and for *destination* stages it is before the following commands can start in those stages.

Comment: So, if `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT` specified as a source stage does the vertex shader pipeline itself counts? Or should I specify later pipeline (`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_CONTROL_SHADER_BIT` is a closest)?

Comment: @nikitablack: Why would you specify a later stage if you wanted to synchronize with an earlier one? That would be an incredibly bad API, wouldn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe... I don't know. If there wouldn't be _source_ and _destination_ stages then one have to specify earlier or later stage. And I still can't find the place in specs which clearly answers my question.

Comment: @nikitablack: You're overthinking it. The source stage is the source of the thing you want to synchronize with, the stage where the operation that you're synchronizing with lives. Period. There's no "beginning" or "end" of the stage; there is just the stage.